# Radio take name from radiogroup in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

how I can automaticly pickup a name from radiogroup and pass it to radio element:

```
xtype: 'radiogroup', 
fieldLabel: 'Is Sale scheduled',
name: 'SaleScheduled',

items: [
{ boxLabel: 'Yes', name: 'SaleScheduled', inputValue: 'YES' },
{ boxLabel: 'No', name: 'SaleScheduled', inputValue: 'NO' }
],
....
```

I tryed to use name: this.getName() or this.findParentByType ('radiogroup')
I try to created extended radiogroup element that will have to chooses Yes or No and I can have it defined as xtype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you're looking for a `YesNoRadioGroup` which passes its name onto its child elements:

```
Ext.ns('Ext.ux');
Ext.ux.YesNoGroup = Ext.extend(Ext.form.RadioGroup, {
  constructor: function(cfg) {
    cfg = cfg || {};
    cfg.items = [
      { boxLabel: 'Yes', name: cfg.name, inputValue: 'YES' },
      { boxLabel: 'No', name: cfg.name, inputValue: 'NO' }
    ];
    Ext.ux.YesNoGroup.superclass.constructor.call(this, cfg);
  }
});
Ext.reg('yes-no-group', Ext.ux.YesNoGroup);
```

Alternatively you could do the same as above but add an `addItem` function which does similar work if you want more flexibility.